# could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.dll or one of its dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I am running visual studio 2012 and I have installed mvc 4.0. on my machine. Though I am targetting .Net v4.0 
I have added a reference to System.Net.Http.dll. I need to make some json calls.
Everything is working fine... on my machine.
When I am installing the executable (wpf application) on a machine running Windows Xp there is an exception stating that **could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.dll or one of its dependencies.**
I have added to the installation folder all the contents of mvc4 assemblies folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies

and still nothing.

What do I need to include to the installation in order to make my aplpication run on windows XP?

Running the mvc 4.0 installation is not an option. I need to be running one installation and one only. The one of my application.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

System.net.http is a .NET framework 4.5 namespace, which is not supported by Windows XP.

Comment: There is a version for System.Net.Http.dll for .net v 4.0